# Change the maximum height of maximised window

Tags: 18.04, themes, gnome-shell

I want a maximized window to have a height 40px below the top of the screen, filling the rest of the space, in Ubuntu 18.04 running with Gnome v3.28.1.

I have tried using `xdotool windowmove` to position a window 40px below the top, however this fails for windows not of the correct size. Using `xdotool windowresize` doesn't work for maximised windows, and even after removing their maximised property using `wmctrl`, it has issues for windows with stepped resizes such as Gnome Terminal.

Is there a way to change the height of a maximised window, or to add some margin above each window?

**Further researching:**

I've found something in the Gnome documentation that looks promising, but am unsure where or how to use this to specify the maximum height. Any help?

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-geometry-hints